# Jmeter - Test scenario 1000 users are visiting multiple static pages

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, test-strategy, test-report

`Test Scenario details:`

1. 800 users on Web site and going up to 1200.

We need split of users in following way:

- 200 Users on Home page
- 50 users on categories page
- 450 users on Web page #1
- 200 on web page #2
- and 100 on web page #3

These users are visiting pages and reading articles so there is delay between next click (1-2 minute). Can I record a scenario in a real way with appropriate delay.

**Example:**

1. I will visit home page
2. select the article
3. click on it
4. read the article
5. select second one and read again.

This activity will take 4-5 min for a user. I need to repeat the scenario for 1000 users. what is the best way to perform it in `jmeter`.

How can I export report for this scenario so it will be easy to understand how users are visiting pages. If there will be errors, we need to understand how did we perform the test and what are the conditions where we got the error.

Please suggest, how should we do this?

Answer (score 2):

To simulate users you must use ***Thread Group*** or ***Concurrency Thread Group***:

[image: JMeter components to simulate users]

So I will suggest you start adding to your **testplan**:

1. **One ThreadGroup/Conc.ThreadGroup** configured to reach a target *concurrency* (number of users surfing your website at one time) of 1200, probably with a couple of ramp-up steps to pass from 0 to 600 to 1200 users; also how long do you want these steps to last? How long do you want the whole session to last? Fill in the data in the component.
2. **Add a [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) to your *Thread Group***: at each user's action the Switch Controller will decide which action to do: go to home page, go to webpage 1 or go to webpage 2 or surf categories. It will decide which action to perform according to the probability you can assign to every child of the Switch Controller to be executed for. Read the docs and some examples for the Switch Controller to figure out how this would happen.
3. **Add multiple [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)** ([HTTP Requests](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)) as child elements of the *Switch Controller*:

_one for getting to the Home Page
_one for getting to the Categories Page
_one for getting to Web Page 1
_one for getting to Web Page 2
_ ...and so on

[image: example]

You can add a [Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) like Constant Timer to each one of these elements to simulate read time.

**Results**: 
to check how the test went, use **[listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners)** to check results. Typically ***View Results Tree*** and ***Summary Report*** are the most handy ones.

There are many details that could be added to what above described but for the sake of shortness I omitted, but you may start as suggested and adjust your test or enhance it while figuring out how it's working and getting to know JMeter components.

Hope that helped a bit.

Enjoy testing.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can easily implement users "crawling" the site using [HTML Link Parser](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser) or a suitable [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to implement more custom logic in choosing the next link, see [How to Spider a Site with JMeter - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-spider-site-jmeter-tutorial) article for comprehensive information on JMeter configuration to simulate users opening random links.
2. With regards to delay between requests you can use i.e. [Uniform Random Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Uniform_Random_Timer) which produces delay not less than "Constant Delay Offset" + whatever you specify in "Random Delay Maximum" so for "reading" time from 1 to 2 minutes it will be `60000` in both fields

   [image: JMeter Uniform Random Timer]